# R Shiny: Plotly pie chart not showing up?

Tags: r, csv, shiny, plotly, donut-chart

Edit: it's apparently system-related as three individual commenters have proven my code to be working.

How can I figure out what I need to change in my server to get this working?

I've published the complete csv's to eliminate any codepage error that perhaps didn't show up in the logs.
[Rutte2.csv](https://gitlab-minfin.nl/datasets/Begroting.Rutte2.csv)
[Rutte3.csv](https://gitlab-minfin.nl/datasets/Begroting.Rutte3.csv)

My screen (laptop, server is headless):
[image: My screen still shows a blank space above the table]

```
schoutencc@vps-01-minfin:/var/www/shiny-server$ sudo cat /var/log/shiny-server/test-shiny-20210716-192927-36317.log

Attaching package: ‘dplyr’

The following objects are masked from ‘package:stats’:

    filter, lag

The following objects are masked from ‘package:base’:

    intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

Loading required package: ggplot2

Attaching package: ‘plotly’

The following object is masked from ‘package:ggplot2’:

    last_plot

The following object is masked from ‘package:stats’:

    filter

The following object is masked from ‘package:graphics’:

    layout


Listening on http://127.0.0.1:36317
schoutencc@vps-01-minfin:/var/www/shiny-server$
```

---

Must be something trivial, but I apparently cannot see it. Am trying to visualize some data into a donut using R/shiny with the plotly library. Data comes in from three csv's (two of which are merged, third will be used to draw lines between the segments later on).

During debugging, I also have a plain data table in my output so I can see the data is read correctly. The table is populated according to my expectations, so the data side of it seems to function properly.

Then comes adding the donut - for now simply having identically sized sections, one for each chapter. Can't make the minimum example much simpler than this. At a later stage, I will play with segment sizing, lines connecting the segments etc.

Alas, my code renders exactly nothing. Well, it does render a white space on the web page above the data table, which means to me that the code is executed error free but that it just doesn't populate for some reason.

No errors appear in the log.

Current code:

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)

ui <- fluidPage(
  plotlyOutput("plot"),
  dataTableOutput("rawdata")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  # Read two csv's containing columns named chapter, article etc.
  dtRutte2 <- read.csv("Begroting.Rutte2.csv", sep=';', fileEncoding="Windows-1252")
  dtRutte3 <- read.csv("Begroting.Rutte3.csv", sep=';', fileEncoding="Windows-1252")

  # Merge these two csv's into one and filter out duplicates
  dtBegroting <- rbind(dtRutte2, dtRutte3) %>% group_by(Begrotingshoofdstuk, Artikelnummer) %>% mutate(rn=row_number()) %>% filter(rn==1) %>% ungroup()

  # Not used yet, will populate a number of internally connecting lines
  dtHerverkavelingen <- read.csv("Herverkavelingen.Rutte3.csv")

  # For debugging purposes: show plain data
  output$rawdata <- renderDataTable(dtBegroting)

  # Construct a pie/donut chart using field 'Chapter name' as label and field 'rn' (see above, always 1) as value to ensure visually uniform distribution add a locale to avoid errors in gsub saying input string is invalid in this locale
  pie <- dtBegroting %>% plot_ly(labels=~Begrotingsnaam, values=~rn, type='pie', textinfo='label', insidetextorientation='radial')
  pie <- pie %>% layout(title='Begrotingshoofdstukken', xaxis=list(showgrid=FALSE, zeroline=FALSE, showticklabels=FALSE), yaxis=list(showgrid=FALSE, zeroline=FALSE, showticklabels=FALSE))
  pie <- pie %>% add_pie(hole=0.6)
  pie <- pie %>% config(locale='nl')

  output$plot <- renderPlotly(pie)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Sample from the csv's (files identical in layout, only different year):

```
Begrotingsjaar;Begrotingshoofdstuk;Begrotingsnaam;Artikelnummer;Artikelnaam
2019;B;Gemeentefonds;2;Onderzoek
2019;B;Gemeentefonds;3;Programma
2019;B;Gemeentefonds;4;Integratie-uitkering sociaal domein
2019;C;Provinciefonds;1;Provinciefonds
2019;F;Diergezondheidsfonds;1;Bewaking en bestrijding van dierziekten
2019;H;BES-fonds;1;BES-fonds
2019;I;De Koning;1;Grondwettelijke uitkering aan de leden vh Koninklijk Huis
2019;I;De Koning;2;Functionele uitgaven van de Koning
2019;I;De Koning;3;Doorbelaste uitgaven van andere begrotingen
```

Comment: Hi, i ran your code and I have a page with a pie plot and a table, with no errors. You're saying you have a white space at the position where the pie plot should be ?

Comment: Same on my machine. Code works fine.

Comment: It works on mine too!

Comment: Crap. So that means it's somehow system specific. Thanks for checking though!

Comment: How can I narrow down what part of my system needs tweaking to get this working?

Comment: Have eliminated any lines with special characters to rule that out and have reinstalled plotly using sudo su - -c "R -e \"install.packages('plotly', repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')\""  --> No luck yet...